# Powershell - Process to test a file for lock, and then document process locking file with counter?

Tags: powershell, logging

I have been beating myself up over trying to come up with a process to accomplish a specific set of tasks, what I need to do is, test file for a lock from a specific program, if a lock is detected I need to increment a counter by 1 and add that specific file name to a log file for reference, and the file needs to have a tally of the applications (counter) for that specific run.

I really haven't even broke ground on an actual script yet as everything I have researched thus far hasn't looked promising, So I figured I'd see if the guru's here have any idea's or input.

Thanks in advance for anything you can add to helping me make sense of what I'm trying to do here.

Comment: To detect locks from a **specific** program you'll need to use a low-level [Handle](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/handle.aspx) utility from SysInternals.

Answer (score 1):

You can start with something like the code below:

```
#Path to the files list. I'm assuming you will have one complete path per line.
$Paths = gc "c:\Temp\Paths.txt"
#Path to the log file
$logFile = "c:\Temp\Log.txt"
$counter = 0

foreach ($Path in $Paths)
{
    $oFile = New-Object System.IO.FileInfo $Path
    if ((Test-Path -Path $Path) -eq $false)
    {
        continue
    }

    try
    {
        $oStream = $oFile.Open([System.IO.FileMode]::Open, [System.IO.FileAccess]::ReadWrite, [System.IO.FileShare]::None)
        if ($oStream)
        {
            $oStream.Close()
        }
        continue
    }
    catch
    {
        # file is locked by a process.
        $fileLocked = (gci $Path).Name
        $filesLocked = $filesLocked + " " + $fileLocked
        $counter++
    }
}
$out = [string]$counter + $filesLocked
Add-Content -Path $logFile -Value $out
```

See if this works.

Comment: I just realized that the counter is not correctly implemented. Can you also give more information about the files to be tested? Will it be in a txt, or a variable?

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, At the end of this script, I was hoping to have a logfile which has a counter total of all the files that are being locked by the application, as well as a proceeding list of the files that were locked.

This will eventually grow to be a log moving script that removes PHI/PII zips the file up and then moves it to a server & date specific repository, but that will all come after figuring out the mechanics for the lock log.

Comment: The files will come from a text file of servers, and the files in question are also text log files themselves.

Comment: Also there is a specific process that can be locking the files so I need to validate against one specific application, to see if it is locking the files.

Comment: So at the end I am hoping for a output similar to this:

Total locked files: 05
C:\file1.txt
C:\file2.txt
C:\file3.txt
C:\file4.txt
C:\file5.txt

Comment: Edited my answer. By the way, I don't know if you can check which process is locking the file using powershell. You will probably need to use something like https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896655.aspx

Comment: I have tried working with Handle, however it has not proven friendly to work with at all, I have read that there are ways of doing it with the openfiles command, but it requires a system reboot to implement via the command ( openfiles /local on), in a production environment, that's not ideal, although I could eventually manage to get that accomplished on most systems I work with.